# Specify markdown description in csproj file

Tags: msbuild, nuget, dotnet-cli

When using `dotnet pack`, I can use properties like `RepositoryUrl` to use as the resulting `.nuspec` file's repository URL etc.

But what property do I set to specify markdown content? Is it even possible to specify via `.csproj` files?

If not, how do I do it in a `.nuspec` file? The documentation is very lacking. According to [this link](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Package-README.md-support), some interns have apparently published the feature - **but how do I use it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: You can use `NuspecProperties` as a Semicolon separated list of key=value pairs.
[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj) the complete command reference for csproj, in particular you have to set the `documentation` property as below reference:

According to this [Nuspec documentation](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Packaging-Documentation-within-the-nupkg)

You can specify the property documentation
`<documentation src="documentation.md" />`
in your `.nuspec` file.

- target defaults to package root
- Supported formats - md
- On pack, strip source value, append the target value with the source file name - `<documentation target="documentation.md"/>`. (this is to help the gallery and the client know the path to the documentation file in the package and the file name.extension. Allows for extension validation, etc.)
- nuget spec will add
  `<!-- e.g. <documentation src="documentation.md"/>. Learn more at https://aka.ms/nugetPackageDocumentation--> 
  <documentation src=""/>`
- package submitted to NuGet.org - target should not be null

Sidenote: this answer comes with a documentation resource published later than when the question was asked.

Comment: Yes that's for the `.nuspec`, but what if I want to add it to the `.csproj`?

Comment: You can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj) all the metadata properties you can set in the `.csproj` file. Unfortunately the documentation property is not there, so I assume that the only thing you can do is specify it in the `.nuspec` file.

Comment: Okay. Thanks either way.

Comment: Ooooh, it seems you can actually use the NuspecProperties argument for it. Can you correct your answer to reflect this, and I will mark it as answered?

Comment: fixed the answer